# Options box in Android placed over other elements

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello and thanks for taking the time!

I'm somewhat new to Android, and working on an app that has a basic search field and some search results. Below the search field I'd like to add more options in a sliding down box, in such way that this box would be expanded to be placed above the elements below the search box, as can be seen here:
http://bit.ly/13Ynw5V (click on the menu icon to slide down the box).

What would you say be the most elegant way to implement this sliding box?

It's worth noting, that the sliding effect would be really nice, but it's not the main issue here - I'm more interested in the open/close functionality, and correctly placing the box OVER the results box.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a [look here](http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html)

Comment: Thanks! I've actually implemented such menu using the Navigation Drawer (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), but what I'm looking for now is an element that is expanded over other elements on the screen. Please take a look at the link - I hope it helps understanding the problem.